# submitting form prop is not able to disable button in react-final form. Using 3.6.4 version of react-final-form

Tags: react-final-form, final-form

I am creating a form using `react-final-form` library version `3.6.4`. When click of submit button I have used submitting prop to disable submit button until a response is received. However, it seems button is not getting disabled.

```
<Form onSubmit={onSubmit} render={({handleSubmit, submitting, pristine, invalid}) => (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
       <button type='submit' disabled={pristine || invalid || submitting}>Submit</button>
    </form>
)}
/>
```

Comment: If anyone of pristine, invalid or submitting is true the button should be disabled. So if invalid is false we are surely going to check value of submitting prop which should have been true on form submit.

Comment: Can you create a codepen for this?

Comment: await keyword was missing for async function. After adding await keyword submitting prop of react-final-form was working as expected.

Comment: @Swapneel Please elaborate a bit, i think you are talking about onSubmit function. Also add an answer and accept that so question is closed properly.